# Dice simulator input - Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to figure out why any input starting with 'y' keeps this game going....looking at the code it appears only 'y' or 'yes' should keep it going but I could enter 'yensdg', 'yyyy' etc and it still loops.

Any ideas?  Thanks

```
from random import randint
repeat = True
while repeat:
    print('You rolled', randint(1,6))
    print('Do you want to roll again?')
    repeat = ('y' or 'yes') in input().lower()
```

Comment: @vaultah if I had a dollar everytime someone got caught with that pseudo-natural language syntax that fails in python...

Comment: 'y' in input().lower(), this statement will return true if 'y' is present anywhere in the input string. Like if the input is 'thisisarandominputwithy' it will return true, because it has 'y' in the end.

Comment: Change the last line to: repeat = input().lower() in ['y', 'yes']

Comment: That would solve your issue

Comment: @KshitijMittal  Thank you, that solved it.  Also, sorry for the duplicate question

Comment: I have added the same as an answer below so that others can read. I think it was marked duplicate by mistake and now has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'y' in input().lower(), this statement will return true if 'y' is present anywhere in the input string. Like if the input is 'thisisarandominputwithy' it will return true, because it has 'y' in the end

Change the last line to:

```
repeat = input().lower() in ['y', 'yes']
```